# Using jquery, how can I select all the DIVs in my document with ID names containing specific text?

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, how can I select all the DIVs in my document with ID names containing specific text?

I want to select all the elements that contain 'parent', the problem is the string parent might be in the middle of the string.

I've been trying to use:

```
var allcontent_collection = $('div[id^=.*parent.*]')
```

It is not working. Should it or am I completely wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the [attribute-contains (`*=`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead, like this:

```
var allcontent_collection = $("div[id*='parent']")
```

Comment: I don't think you need the single quotes there, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @hookedonwinter - They are inddeed optional for *this* example, just giving a more general approach that works for others as well :)